# Converting image url to complete html image tag

Tags: php

I am working on comments thing and i want my user to be able to post image url which i will change into image url with tag

my function

```
function ImageTag($text) {
    // The Regular Expression filter
    $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
    // The Text you want to filter for urls
    if(preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {
           // make the urls hyper links
           $matches = array_unique($url[0]);
           foreach($matches as $match) {
                $check = substr($match, -4);
                if ($check == ".jpg" || $check == ".png" || $check == ".gif" || $check == "jpeg" || $check == ".JPG" || $check == ".PNG" || $check == ".GIF" || $check == "JPEG"){
                    $replacement = "<br/><img src=$match>";
                    $text = str_replace($match, $replacement, $text);
                }
           }
           return nl2br($text);
    } else {
           // if no urls in the text just return the text
           return nl2br($text);
    }
}

$text = "The text you want to filter goes here. <img src='http://static.php.net/www.php.net/images/php.gif'> http://www.facebook.com http://static.php.net/www.php.net/images/php.gif";
$content = ImageTag($text);
echo $content;
```

I am half done with my function but i am not sure how to solve image which are already have html tags

**This is what i am getting**

[image]

source code:

```
The text you want to filter goes here. <img src="&lt;br/&gt;&lt;img src=http://static.php.net/www.php.net/images/php.gif&gt;"> http://www.facebook.com <br><img src="http://static.php.net/www.php.net/images/php.gif">
```

Comment: Why not use a data uri for image?

Comment: I dont know anything about data uri but i will check

Comment: Instead of / In addition to posting a screenshot, post the original (user contributed) text, and the generated HTML, would be more helpful.

Comment: @deerox You allow user to contribute HTML content?

Comment: @Passerby Yes in comment box

Comment: @deerox If you insist...security consideration aside, if you expect the content to be HTML a like, you may want to use parser (e.g. DOMDocument), not RegExp, to deal with it.

Comment: @Passerby I will update it.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by decoding html tags ([htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)), then strip tags ([strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)) and replace 'src=' with a blank